# Multiple Foreign Keys from a column to a table

Tags: sql

This is my tables description :

**Ticket**

```
Id                      int    pk
ShowTicketStateID_FK    int
TicketStateID_FK        int
```

**TicketState**

```
Id                      int
Name                    int
```

Actually, the `TicketState` has two foreign keys to `Ticket`table.

Here is some rows from `Ticket` table :

```
1    1    1
2    2    1
3    1    2
...
```

And here is rows for `TicketState`

```
1   'sold'
2   'reserved'
```

Now i want this Result set :

```
1    sold      sold
2    reserved  sold
3    sold      reserved
```

How should I select rows from ticket table with both states name?

Comment: Please show a more complete example, with sample data, etc.

Comment: Just do two joins on each of the foreign keys...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT T.ID, S1.Name AS ShowState, S2.Name AS TicketState
  FROM Ticket AS T
  JOIN TicketState AS S1 ON T1.ShowTicketStateID = S1.ID
  JOIN TicketState AS S2 ON T1.TicketStateID     = S2.ID
```

The key concept is using the two different table aliases for the TicketState table in a single query.  The table has to be scanned twice (speaking loosely), once for the ShowTicketStateID lookup and once for the TicketStateID lookup.